# Subsetting / unmerging data frames in R based on a variable

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, subset

I have two data frames in R.

```
one <- data.frame( x = letters[1:10] , y = 1:10, z = rnorm(10))    
two <- data.frame( x = letters[1:20] , y = 1:20, z = one$z)
```

I want to "un-merge" these data frames based on the variable x... What I mean is that... I want to create a third data frame that has all of the records from `two` in it that are *not* in data frame `one`. So I want to look at `two` and say "get rid of all of the rows that are in this data frame that also happen to be in `one`. Does that make sense? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You mean something like `anti_join(two, one)` using `dplyr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution in base R:

```
#using as.character since one$x and two$x are factors in this case
> two[ as.character(one$x) != as.character(two$x), ]
   x  y          z
11 k 11 -0.6680130
12 l 12 -1.0501888
13 m 13 -1.0987269
14 n 14  1.0045557
15 o 15 -0.6002310
16 p 16  1.3162201
17 q 17 -0.1209575
18 r 18 -1.0129547
19 s 19  2.4832670
20 t 20  0.4660156
```

Comment: Thanks again! If I'm dealing with factors rather than characters, how would that change the code? I tried using `as.factor` in my data set but was told `Error in Ops.factor(as.factor(one$EntrezUID), as.factor(two$EntrezUID)) :  level sets of factors are different`

Comment: Exactly. Since you use factors in your data set, you need to convert them into character which is what my code above does inside the square brackets. No need to specify `as.factor`. You need to use my code exactly as it is, the code shouldn't change at all since you use factors.

Comment: And if you are dealing with factors instead of characters then you still need to convert those into character. The actual class in the data.frame will not change anyway.